# Does Python support zero-copy I/O?

Tags: python, file-io, io, zero-copy

I have two open file objects, `dest` and `src`. File object `dest` is opened for writing, with the seek position placed at some offset within the file, and file object `src` is opened for reading. What I need to do is simply read from the current position in `src` to EOF and transfer the contents to `dest` as quickly as possible.

If I were programming in Java, I could utilize the [`FileChannel#transferTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo%28long,%20long,%20java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel%29) method to perform zero-copy file I/O.

Does Python also support zero-copy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since version 3.3, Python has [`os.sendfile`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.sendfile), which interfaces to various Unix variants' `sendfile(2)` zero-copy I/O interfaces. It operates on file descriptors, not general file-like objects. For older Pythons, there's [py-sendfile](https://github.com/giampaolo/pysendfile).

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.8, you can use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) (and others from `shutil`) which will internally use zero-copy if possible, such as `os.sendfile`, and if not possible, fall back to a simple read-write loop.

See [the `shutil` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil-platform-dependent-efficient-copy-operations) for details.
Or [issue 33671 (Efficient zero-copy for shutil.copy* functions (Linux, OSX and Win))](https://bugs.python.org/issue33671).
And [the corresponding (merged) pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7160).

You might also be interested in copy-on-write support or server-side copy support. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492317/copy-file-in-python-for-zfs-or-other-fs-with-cow-copy-on-write-support), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492932/ficlone-vs-ficlonerange-vs-copy-file-range-for-copy-on-write-support).
The [`os.copy_file_range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.copy_file_range) (since Python 3.8) would do that. See [issue 37159 (Use copy_file_range() in shutil.copyfile())](https://bugs.python.org/issue37159) (maybe Python 3.9 or 3.10).