# Copy file in Python with copy-on-write (COW)

Tags: python, copy-on-write

My filesystem (FS) (ZFS specifically) supports copy-on-write (COW), i.e. a copy (if done right) is a very cheap constant operation, and does not actually copy the underlying content. The content is copied only once I write/modify the new file.

Actually, I just found out, ZFS-on-Linux actually has not implemented that for userspace yet (right?).
But e.g. BTRFS or XFS has.
(See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562619/how-does-zfs-copy-on-write-work-for-large-files),
[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/5n4e8d/zfs_on_linux_does_copyonwrite_work/),
[here](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/405),
[here](http://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/group/zfs-discuss/browse_thread/thread/9af181ed0129b77c#).)

For the (GNU) `cp` utility, you would pass `--reflink=always` option
(see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80351/why-is-cp-reflink-auto-not-the-default-behaviour/152639).)
`cp` calls `ioctl (dest_fd, FICLONE, src_fd)`
(see [here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/00ea4bacf6063ccc125209d5186f8f2382c6f0d4/src/copy.c#L408), [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/ioctl_ficlone.2.en.html)).

How would I get this behavior (if possible) in Python?

I assume that "zero-copy" (e.g. [here via `os.sendfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456181/does-python-support-zero-copy-i-o/)) would not result in such behavior, right? Because looking at `shutil`s `_fastcopy_sendfile` implementation ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7160/files#diff-db8ac59326160713929e0e1973aef54f0280fe9f154ef24d14244909a0e0689bR143)), it is still a loop around `os.sendfile` using some custom byte count (supposed to be the block size, `max(os.fstat(infd).st_size, 2 ** 23)`). Or would it?

The COW, is this on a file level, or block level?

If possible, I want this to be generic and cross-platform as well, although my question here is somewhat Linux focused.
A related question specifically about Mac seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945481/how-to-clone-files-with-python).
The MacOSX `cp` has the `-c` option to clone a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While searching further, I actually found the answer, and a related issue report.

[Issue 37157 (shutil: add reflink=False to file copy functions to control clone/CoW copies (use copy_file_range))](https://bugs.python.org/issue37157)
is exactly about that, which would use [`FICLONE`/`FICLONERANGE`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html) on Linux.

So I assume that `shutil` would support this in upcoming Python versions (maybe starting with Python 3.9?).

There is [`os.copy_file_range`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html#os.copy_file_range) (since Python 3.8), which wraps [`copy_file_range`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) (Linux).

However, according to [issue 37159 (Use copy_file_range() in shutil.copyfile() (server-side copy))](https://bugs.python.org/issue37159), Giampaolo Rodola:

> Nope, [copy_file_range] doesn't [support CoW] (see man page). We can simply use FICLONE (cp does the same).

However, I'm not sure this is correct, as the [`copy_file_range` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) says:

> copy_file_range() gives filesystems an opportunity to implement
> "copy acceleration" techniques, such as the use of reflinks
> (i.e., two or more inodes that share pointers to the same copy-
> on-write disk blocks) or server-side-copy (in the case of NFS).

[Issue 26826 (Expose new copy_file_range() syscall in os module)](https://bugs.python.org/issue26826) has this comment by Giampaolo Rodola:

> I think data deduplication / CoW / reflink copy is better implemented via FICLONE. "cp --reflink" uses it, I presume because it's older than copy_file_range(). ...

Again, as noted already in the question, this does not work on ZFS yet, see [this issue](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/405).