# Difference of FICLONE vs FICLONERANGE vs copy_file_range (for copy-on-write support)

Tags: linux, file-copying

I wonder about an efficient way to copy files (on Linux, on a FS which supports [**copy-on-write (COW)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)).
Specifically, I want that my implementation uses copy-on-write if possible, but otherwise falls back to other efficient variants. Specifically, I also care about **server-side copy** (supported by [SMB](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Server-Side_Copy), [NFS](https://linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/Server_Side_Copy) and [others](https://serverfault.com/questions/566708/which-file-transfer-protocols-support-server-side-copying)), and also [**zero-copy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) (i.e. bypassing the CPU or memory if possible).

(This question is not really specific to any programming language. It could be C or C++, but also any other like Python, Go or whatever has bindings to the OS syscalls, or has any way to do a syscall. If this is confusing to you, just answer in C.)

It looks like [`ioctl_ficlonerange`, `ioctl_ficlone` (i.e. `ioctl` with `FICLONE` or `FICLONERANGE`)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html) support copy-on-write (COW). Specifically `FICLONE` is used by GNU `cp` ([here](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/00ea4bacf6063ccc125209d5186f8f2382c6f0d4/src/copy.c#L408), via `--reflink`).

Then there is also [`copy_file_range`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html), which also seems to support COW, and server-side-copy.
([LWN about copy_file_range](https://lwn.net/Articles/659523/).)

It sounds as if `copy_file_range` is more generic (e.g. it supports server-side-copy; not sure if that is supported by `FICLONE`).

However, `copy_file_range` seems to have some issues.
E.g. [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24399), Paul Eggert comments:

> [copy_file_range]'s man page
> says it uses a size_t (not off_t) to count the number of bytes to be
> copied, which is a strange choice for a file-copying API.

Are there situations where `FICLONE` would work better/different than `copy_file_range`?

Are there situations where `FICLONE` would work better/different than `FICLONERANGE`?

Specifically, assuming the underlying FS supports this, and assume you want to copy a file. I ask about the support of these functions for the functionality of:

- [Copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) support
- Server-side copy support
- [Zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) support

Are they (`FICLONE`, `FICLONERANGE`, `copy_file_range`) always performing exactly the same operation? (Assuming the underlying FS supports copy-on-write, and/or server-side copy.)

Or are there situations where it make sense to use `copy_file_range` instead of `FICLONE`? (E.g. COW only works with `copy_file_range` but not with `FICLONE`. Or the other way around. Or can this never happen?)

Or formulating the same question differently: Would `copy_file_range` always be fine, or are there situations where I would want to use `FICLONE` instead?

Why does GNU `cp` use `FICLONE` and not `copy_file_range`? (Is there a technical reason, or is this just historic?)

Related: GNU `cp` originally did not use `reflink` by default (see [comment by the GNU coreutils maintainer Pádraig Brady](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152639/2954)).
However, that was changed recently ([this commit](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/25725f9d41735d176d73a757430739fb71c7d043), [bug report 24400](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24400)), i.e. COW behavior is the default now (if possible) (`--reflink=auto`).

Related [question about Python for COW support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492317/copy-file-in-python-for-zfs-or-other-fs-with-cow-copy-on-write-support/).

Related [discussion about FICLONE vs copy_file_range by Python developers](https://bugs.python.org/issue37157). I.e. this seems to be a valid question, and it's not totally clear whether to use `FICLONE` or `copy_file_range`.

Related [Syncthing documentation about the choice of methods for copying data between files](https://docs.syncthing.net/advanced/folder-copyrangemethod.html), and
[Syncthing issue about `copy_file_range` and others for efficient file copying, e.g. with COW support](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/4271).
It also suggests that it is not so clear that `FICLONE` would do the same as `copy_file_range`, so their solution is to just try all of them, and fallback to the next, in this order:
ioctl (with FICLONE), copy_file_range, sendfile, duplicate_extents, standard.

Related [issue by Go developers on the usage of `copy_file_range`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/36817).
It sounds as if they agree that `copy_file_range` is always to be preferred over [`sendfile`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html).

(Question copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492932/ficlone-vs-ficlonerange-vs-copy-file-range-for-copy-on-write-support) but I don't see how this is too less focused. This question is very focused and asks a very specific thing (whether FICLONE and copy_file_range behave the same), and should be extremely clear. I formulated the question in multiple different ways, to make the question even more clear. This question is also extremely well researched, and should already be very valuable to the community as-is with all the references. I would have been very happy if I would have found such a question by itself, even without answers, when I started researching about the differences between FICLONE and copy_file_range.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Linux vfs doc](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fcadab740480e0e0e9fa9bd272acd409884d431a/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.rst) about `copy_file_range`, `remap_file_range`, `FICLONERANGE`, `FICLONE` and `FIDEDUPERANGE`.

Then see
[`vfs_copy_file_range`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0adc313c4f20639f7e235b8d6719d96a2024cf91/fs/read_write.c#L1506). This first tries to call `remap_file_range` if possible.

`FICLONE` calls `ioctl_file_clone` ([here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fcadab740480e0e0e9fa9bd272acd409884d431a/fs/ioctl.c#L714)),
and `FICLONERANGE` calls `ioctl_file_clone_range`.
`ioctl_file_clone_range` calls the more generic `ioctl_file_clone` ([here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fcadab740480e0e0e9fa9bd272acd409884d431a/fs/ioctl.c#L259)).
`ioctl_file_clone` calls `vfs_clone_file_range` ([here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/fcadab740480e0e0e9fa9bd272acd409884d431a/fs/ioctl.c#L239)).
`vfs_clone_file_range` calls `do_clone_file_range` and that calls `remap_file_range` ([here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/74f602dc96dd854c7b2034947798c1e2a6b84066/fs/remap_range.c#L406)).

I.e. that answers the question. `copy_file_range` is more generic, and anyway tries to call `remap_file_range` (i.e. the same as `FICLONE`/`FICLONERANGE`) first internally.

I think the `copy_file_range` syscall is slightly newer than `FICLONE` though, i.e. it might be possible that `copy_file_range` is not available in your kernel but `FICLONE` is.

In any case, if `copy_file_range` is available, it should be the best solution.

The order done by Syncthing (ioctl (with FICLONE), copy_file_range, sendfile, duplicate_extents, standard) makes sense.